# Fake, animated web 2.0-like tooltip in Delphi

Tags: image, delphi, graphics, delphi-2010

### Initial Explanation

There are certain key areas in my delphi application that I need to highlight. I decided that standard tooltips won't cut it, and dialog boxes are too annoying to be of helpful.

Web 2.0 tooltips (like [this Coda-style bubble example](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html)) are less intrusive & much better for my specific need.

### My attempt to solve the problem

Initially I custom designed a tooltip image, put it in a DevExpress' TdxImage component (which is basically a TImage with transparent PNG support) along with a label and used them as a custom tooltip but...

**My problem is** How can I animate as in normal/web tooltips? I tried AnimateWindow(). It worked, but **text didn't appear** at all (text isn't drawn, only the image is shown)

```
// Prepare tooltip text
cxTooltipLabel.Caption := 'Translated or dynamic tooltip text';
cxTooltipLabel.Visible := True;
cxTooltipLabel.BringToFront;

// Load custom tooltip image
cxImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExePath + 'data\tooltip.png');

// Show tooltip!
AnimateWindowProc(cxImage.Handle, 250, AW_CENTER OR AW_ACTIVATE);
```

It's important to note that image is a **transparent PNG**, I'm willing to use any solution other than AnimateWindowProc() as long as it's **not heavy** and give me **smooth animation as in the [Coda tooltips](http://uhleeka.com/demo/bubbletip/)**

Any idea guys?

Comment: Using a layered window with GDI+

Comment: @bummi: Very interesting...care to expand/share an example/link in Delphi please?

Answer (score 0):

I have got a snippet, far away from what you are really searching, but the technique is the one I would recommend. Anything called EXGDIxxx is from http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7 (free), just renamed and adapted.

```
unit Unit_Outline;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
   ExtCtrls,EXGDIPAPI,EXGDIPOBJ, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
   FDown:Boolean;
   FStartx,FstartY ,FendX,FEndY:Integer;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }

  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
 Function ColorToTGPColor (c : Tcolor; trans : Byte = 255):TGPColor;
Type
 TBarry=Array[0..3] of Byte;
Var
 Barry:TBarry;
 R:Byte;
begin
  move(C,Barry,4);
  R:=Barry[2];
  Barry[2]:=Barry[0];
  Barry[0]:=R;
  Barry[3]:=trans;
  move(Barry,Result,4);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   FStartx := X;
   FstartY := Y;
   FDown := true;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if ssleft in shift then
    begin
     FEndx := X;
     FEndY := Y;
     Paint;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
   C_Alpha=0;
var
   DestPoint, srcPoint:TPoint;
   winSize:TSize;
   DC         : HDC;
   blendfunc  : BLENDFUNCTION;
   Owner : HWnd;
   curWinStyle:Integer;
   exStyle:Dword;
   BackImage:TBitMap;
   Graphics :  TGPGraphics;
   Brush:TGPSolidBrush;
   FontFamily : TGPFontFamily;
   fmt:TGPStringFormat;
   aFont : TGPFont;
   Pen:TGPPen;
   xx,yy:Integer;
   path : TGPGraphicsPath;
begin

  DC := GetDC(0);
  BackImage:=TBitMap.Create;
  BackImage.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
  BackImage.Width := Width;
  BackImage.Height := Height;
  BackImage.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  BackImage.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Width,Height));

  Graphics :=  TGPGraphics.Create(BackImage.Canvas.Handle);
  graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
  graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);
  Brush:=TGPSolidBrush.Create(ColorToTGPColor(clRed,200));
  FontFamily := TGPFontFamily.Create('Arial narrow');
  aFont := TGPFont.Create(FontFamily,80);
  Pen:=TGPPen.Create(ColorToTGPColor(clRed,200));
  fmt:=TGPStringFormat.Create;
  try
  path := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  path.AddString('Test',-1,FontFamily,1,150,MakePoint(100,100),fmt);
  Graphics.DrawPath(pen,path);
  // Graphics.FillPath(brush,path);
  path.Free;
  FontFamily.Free;
  FontFamily := TGPFontFamily.Create('Times New Roman');

  path := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  path.AddString(FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss',now),-1,FontFamily,FontStyleBold or FontStyleItalic,200,MakePoint(200,200),fmt);
  pen.SetWidth(2);
  pen.SetColor(ColorToTGPColor(clNavy,230));
  Graphics.DrawPath(pen,path);
  // Graphics.FillPath(brush,path);
  path.Free;
  pen.Free;

//  Graphics.DrawString(FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss',now),-1,aFont,MakePoint(0.0,0),Brush);
   winSize.cx := width;
   winSize.cy := Height;
   srcPoint.x := 0;
   srcPoint.y := 0;

   DestPoint := BoundsRect.TopLeft;
   exStyle := GetWindowLongA(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
   if (exStyle and WS_EX_LAYERED = 0) then SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, (exStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT) );


   With blendFunc do
   begin
     AlphaFormat := 1;
     BlendFlags := 0;
     BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
     SourceConstantAlpha := 255 - C_Alpha;
   end;

   UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, DC, @DestPoint, @winSize, BackImage.Canvas.Handle,  @srcPoint,clBlack, @blendFunc, 2);

   finally
   ReleaseDC(0, DC);
   BackImage.Free;
   Graphics.Free;
   Brush.Free;
   FontFamily.free;
   aFont.Free;
   fmt.Free;
   end;

end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
   SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE );
   DoubleBuffered := true;

end;

procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormPaint(self);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid this isn't working; I need this for Delphi 2010, prodigy's code (`DirectDraw.pas` specifically) failed to compile under this delphi version (many errors like this: `[DCC Error] DirectDraw.pas(358): E2154 Type 'IDirectDrawSurface' needs finalization - not allowed in variant record` with the latest files downloaded from the prodigy.com website)

Comment: Remove the Directdrawcode from prodigy, Emba has it's own.
Is working 4 me from D7 to 2005,2007,2009,Delphi XE didn't try with XE3 yet (out of office)

Comment: I couldn't remove it (Delphi **2010** would complaint), but I got the [latest files from here](http://delphi-dx9sdk.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/delphi-dx9sdk/Headers/DirectDraw.pas?revision=1.4) and it worked...indeed it's very far, but now I clearly see your point about transparent layered window drawing...

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, I should draw the tooltips on a special form (using GDI+) and pass its handle when calling AnimateWindowProc() ie.  `AnimateWindowProc(TransparentForm.Handle, 250, AW_CENTER OR AW_ACTIVATE);`, correct?

Comment: You won't animate via AnimateWindowProc, all animation is done in painting on the layered window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another very cheap way, which one you can use AnimateWindowProc.
There is no magic in the code, perhaps it meets your needs.
[coda_src](http://www.bummisoft.de/download/coda_src.zip)

Comment: Thank you for the code bummi! I took a look at the code, it does have an undesirable focus problem when the tooltip form is shown (can be avoided if I use a control I guess), but now it's much more clear now, thanks!...I'll get back to you later to accept the answer after I adapt the code

Comment: Thanks again bummi & sorry for the late reply, I tried the sample project but I'm afraid it doesn't meet my requirements. I posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679089/delphi-thintwindow-how-to-draw-a-transparent-png) with more details on how I want the end result, thanks again!